# UPDATE jsonb key that have spaces

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using a postgres database, and need to update my jsonb data.
When my key inside jsonb data don't have spaces, it works well. But when I try to update a key that have spaces, don't update.

```
update forms 
  set data = data || '{"RAZÃO SOCIAL":"aaaA","SIGLA":"ASCOM SOUREEEE"}' 
where id = 10;
```

In that case, my query update "SIGLA" , but don't update "RAZÃO SOCIAL".

Any idea to manage this issue? Already replaced the whitespace with %20 and no success.

Comment: [It should work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a02bc1eb0d347773d1fa88409411a099). You need to gather more diagnostic information that "Don't update". Does the query fail with an error code and error message? Does the query succeed, but no matching rows are found?

Comment: The query runs fine. But it doesn't update

Comment: Do you mean PostgreSQL reports that there was 1 row updated but the changes are lost? Do you commit the transaction? Are you positively sure that your code would report errors rather then silencing them?

Comment: Seems like in other version of postgres runs. And yes, I commited the transaction, since it update other values